# Accessing specific value in a list of values

Tags: python, object, dictionary, valuestack

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'153':  |T-shirt| |200| |0| |0|, '764': |Jeans| |350| |0| |0|, '334': |Hatt| |59| |0|   |0|, '324': |Skor| |250| |0| |0|, '234': |Tröja| |300| |0| |0|, '543': |Jacka| |400| |0| |0|}
```

This means that I for example have a key that looks like 153, which access a value of:

```
|T-shirt| |200| |0| |0|
```

What if I would like to do is access 1 of the parts in my value. For exampel, if i type 153 and get|T-shirt| |200| |0| |0|, how then to access the part 200 in my value? If my dict value is: |T-shirt| |200| |0| |0|, i want only to get: 200, bot any of the other parts of the same value. All of my dict values are objects for the class wares, which means that each part that is enclosed by "||" is a attribute.

for exampel:

```
|T-shirt| |200| |0| |0|.
```

Were T-shirt is a self.name attribute, 200 is a self.price attribute, 0(1st one) is a self.quantity and 0(2nd one) is a self.bought attribute.

I only want to access the self.price attribute, how do I do it? I tried indexing my object like:

```
x = wares[T-shirt, 200, 0, 0]
b = x[1]
print(b)
```

but python says that:

```
"object can not be indexed"
```

any one got a tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> d= {'153':  '|T-shirt| |200| |0| |0|', '764': '|Jeans| |350| |0| |0|', '334': '|Hatt| |59| |0|   |0|', '324': '|Skor| |250| |0| |0|', '234': '|Tröja| |300| |0| |0|', '543': '|Jacka| |400| |0| |0|'}
>>> def parts(s):
        return re.findall(r'\|([^\|]+)\|', s)
```

or since regex is evil I would recommend:

```
>>> def parts(s):
        return [x.strip('|') for x in s.split()]    

>>> parts(d['153'])
['T-shirt', '200', '0', '0']
>>> parts(d['153'])[1]
'200'
```

Alternatively you could make things much easier and more readable by making `parts` return a dictionary:

```
>>> def parts(s):
       return dict(zip(('name', 'price', 'quantity', 'bought'), [x.strip('|') for x in s.split()]))

>>> parts(d['153'])['price']
'200'
```

Actually we could make this even better using `collections.namedtuple`

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> def parts(s):
        Item = namedtuple('Item', ('name', 'price', 'quantity', 'bought'))
        return Item(*[x.strip('|') for x in s.split()])


>>> parts(d['153'])
Item(name='T-shirt', price='200', quantity='0', bought='0')
>>> parts(d['153']).price
'200'
```

Comment: So what you are doing is that you are turning my values from 153 into a list, and from the list one can index the object? If you were to get only 200 from parts(d['153]), how would you proceed?

Comment: @Bardolf `parts(d['153'])[1]` though I'm not sure exactly how your data structure works, you might find it easier to work with dictionaries. eg. dict(zip(('item_name', 'foo', 'bar', 'spam'), [x.strip('|') for x in s.split()]))` And then you could access each item like `item['name']`. Again, you haven't given much specific information so I can't be sure what you want

Comment: I have edited the question, would you please have another look?

Comment: noticed now that you used parts(d['153']), should it not be parts(s['153'])?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print dict
{'153': ['T-shirt', '200', '0', '0'], '334': ['Hatt', '59', '0', '0'], '764': ['Jeans', '350', '0', '0'], '543': ['Jacka', '400', '0', '0'], '324': ['Skor', '250', '0', '0'], '234': ['Tr\xc3\xb6ja ', '300', '0', '0']}
>>> dict['153'][1]
'200'
>>>
```

Comment: This looks great but show how you created `dict` (On a side note don't call your dictionary `dict` because it's a builtin name)

Comment: @Pradeep Kanagave when I tried to do as you said, python responded that "'wares' object does not support indexing". This has happened before. Do you have a clue why something like this would happen?